# Why to use local pointer to iterate over a list?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

Say I have the following struct to define list nodes:

```
 struct node {
         int            data;
         struct node*   next;
};
```

And I have this function to get the length of a list:

```
int Length(struct node* head) {
   struct node* current = head;
   int count = 0;
   while (current != NULL) {
      count++;
      current = current->next;
   }
   return count;
}
```

Why would I want to do this: `struct node* current = head;` instead of just iterating over the head?

So, why would this not be ok:

```
int Length(struct node* head) {
   int count = 0;
   while (head != NULL) {
      count++;
      head = head->next;
   }
   return count;
}
```

Doesn't the head lose the scope once it gets inside the Length function, and therefore even if we do head = head->next it won't be affected outside the function?

Thanks

Comment: You can. What you can't do is, for example, int Length(struct node** head) and then pass in a main Lenght(&head);

Comment: What about this: `for (struct node * p = head; p; p = p->next) { ++count; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your two codes snippets are equivalent.

However, there's a school of thought that says that you should never modify function arguments, in order to avoid potential programming errors, and to enhance readability (you're not really modifying the head).  To that end, you will often see people defining as many arguments as possible as `const`.

Comment: But in the case that I don't create a local pointer, that head will be defined local by the compiler right?

Comment: Yes, function parameters are like local variables.

Comment: So if I wanted to modify that head, I would have to pass it with reference as struct node** head I believe, right?

Comment: @HommerSmith: Indeed, the rule is that you need to pass a pointer to the thing you want to modify.  If you want to modify a pointer, then you need to pass a pointer to it...

Comment: ... but in this particular case you would *not* want to change the caller's pointer's value. And remember: the parameter only passes the *value* of the pointer variable, not the thing itself.

Answer (score 1):

A smart compiler will do that anyway. Some people do it for clarity as head to them means the head of the list and current is just the iterator, it's just for readability.

Answer (score 0):

The programmers I know all intuitively assume that the value of an argument which is passed by-value (such as the address referenced by a pointer) remain unchanged throughout the function. Due to this assumption, it's easy to introduce little bugs when extending the function. Imagine I wanted to print a little bit of debug information to your `Length` function:

```
int Length(struct node* head) {
   int count = 0;
   while (head != NULL) {
      count++;
      head = head->next;
   }
   printf( "Length of list at %p is %d\n", head, count );
   return count;
}
```

The larger the function gets (or the more contrived the logic is, or the less attention the guy doing the modification is paying...), the easier this kind of issue can happen.

For short functions, such as `Length`, I personally consider it to be fine (I do it as well).